# What is the pool size of global pooling operations?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

In normal pooling operations we have to mention pool size for pooling operation, like for 2D pooling operations we mention `(2,2)`; however, in global pooling operation it is not required. So is it the same size as input? I am working on Keras. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257321/what-is-global-max-pooling-layer-and-what-is-its-advantage-over-maxpooling-layer) one author mentions that the pooling size is the same as `input size` or `input size-filter size+1`. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of 1D pooling, as mentioned in [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling1d), it takes as input an array of shape `(batch_size, steps, features)` and its output shape is `(batch_size, features)`. So the pool size is equal to `steps`.

In case of 2D pooling, as mentioned in [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling2d), it takes as input an array of shape `(batch_size, rows, cols, channels)` and its output shape is `(batch_size, channels)`. So the pool size is equal to `(rows, cols)`.

In both cases, the pool size is consistent with the intuition behind it: taking maximum value over the whole data axes (i.e. global).

Answer (score 1):

If the input shape is `(None, rows, cols, filters)`, then global pooling uses pool_size of `(rows, cols)`.